PackagesNotFoundError : The following packages are not available from current channels:
I'm trying to build a docker image of a python app based on anaconda :
here's the dockerfile :
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
# setting the working directory 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN conda env create --file environment.yml
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "app", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
EXPOSE 8050
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit","run","main.py","--server.port=8501", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]

i executed conda env export > environment.yml to genarat this file environment.yml
environment.yml content :
name: app
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - altair=5.0.1=py312haa95532_0
  - arrow-cpp=16.1.0=h7cd61ee_0
  - attrs=24.2.0=py312haa95532_0
  - aws-c-auth=0.6.19=h2bbff1b_0
  - aws-c-cal=0.5.20=h2bbff1b_0
  - aws-c-common=0.8.5=h2bbff1b_0
  - aws-c-compression=0.2.16=h2bbff1b_0
  - aws-c-event-stream=0.2.15=hd77b12b_0
  - aws-c-http=0.6.25=h2bbff1b_0
  - aws-c-io=0.13.10=h2bbff1b_0
  - aws-c-mqtt=0.7.13=h2bbff1b_0
  - aws-c-s3=0.1.51=h2bbff1b_0
  - aws-c-sdkutils=0.1.6=h2bbff1b_0
  - aws-checksums=0.1.13=h2bbff1b_0
  - aws-crt-cpp=0.18.16=hd77b12b_0
  - aws-sdk-cpp=1.10.55=hd77b12b_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - blinker=1.6.2=py312haa95532_0
  - boost-cpp=1.82.0=h59b6b97_2
  - bottleneck=1.3.7=py312he558020_0
  - brotli=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_8
  - brotli-bin=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_8
  - brotli-python=1.0.9=py312hd77b12b_8
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h2bbff1b_6
  - c-ares=1.19.1=h2bbff1b_0
  - ca-certificates=2024.11.26=haa95532_0
  - cachetools=5.3.3=py312haa95532_0
  - certifi=2024.8.30=py312haa95532_0
  - charset-normalizer=3.3.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - click=8.1.7=py312haa95532_0
  - colorama=0.4.6=py312haa95532_0
  - contourpy=1.3.1=py312h214f63a_0
  - cycler=0.11.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - et_xmlfile=1.1.0=py312haa95532_1
  - expat=2.6.3=h5da7b33_0
  - fonttools=4.51.0=py312h2bbff1b_0
  - freetype=2.12.1=ha860e81_0
  - gflags=2.2.2=hd77b12b_1
  - gitdb=4.0.7=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - gitpython=3.1.43=py312haa95532_0
  - glog=0.5.0=hd77b12b_1
  - greenlet=3.0.1=py312hd77b12b_0
  - htbuilder=0.6.2=py312haa95532_0
  - icc_rt=2022.1.0=h6049295_2
  - icu=73.1=h6c2663c_0
  - idna=3.7=py312haa95532_0
  - importlib-metadata=7.2.1=pyha770c72_0
  - intel-openmp=2023.1.0=h59b6b97_46320
  - jinja2=3.1.4=py312haa95532_0
  - jpeg=9e=h827c3e9_3
  - jsonschema=4.23.0=py312haa95532_0
  - jsonschema-specifications=2023.7.1=py312haa95532_0
  - kiwisolver=1.4.4=py312hd77b12b_0
  - krb5=1.20.1=h5b6d351_0
  - lcms2=2.12=h83e58a3_0
  - lerc=3.0=hd77b12b_0
  - libabseil=20240116.2=cxx17_h5da7b33_0
  - libboost=1.82.0=h3399ecb_2
  - libbrotlicommon=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_8
  - libbrotlidec=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_8
  - libbrotlienc=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_8
  - libclang=14.0.6=default_hb5a9fac_1
  - libclang13=14.0.6=default_h8e68704_1
  - libcurl=8.9.1=h0416ee5_0
  - libdeflate=1.17=h2bbff1b_1
  - libevent=2.1.12=h56d1f94_1
  - libffi=3.4.4=hd77b12b_1
  - libgrpc=1.62.2=hf25190f_0
  - libpng=1.6.39=h8cc25b3_0
  - libpq=12.17=h906ac69_0
  - libprotobuf=4.25.3=hf2fb9eb_0
  - libssh2=1.11.0=h291bd65_0
  - libthrift=0.15.0=h4364b78_2
  - libtiff=4.5.1=hd77b12b_0
  - libwebp-base=1.3.2=h3d04722_1
  - lz4-c=1.9.4=h2bbff1b_1
  - markdown-it-py=2.2.0=py312haa95532_1
  - markupsafe=2.1.3=py312h2bbff1b_0
  - matplotlib=3.9.2=py312haa95532_1
  - matplotlib-base=3.9.2=py312he19b0ae_1
  - mdurl=0.1.0=py312haa95532_0
  - mkl=2023.1.0=h6b88ed4_46358
  - mkl-service=2.4.0=py312h2bbff1b_1
  - mkl_fft=1.3.10=py312h827c3e9_0
  - mkl_random=1.2.7=py312h0158946_0
  - more-itertools=10.3.0=py312haa95532_0
  - numexpr=2.8.7=py312h96b7d27_0
  - numpy=1.26.4=py312hfd52020_0
  - numpy-base=1.26.4=py312h4dde369_0
  - openjpeg=2.5.2=hae555c5_0
  - openpyxl=3.1.5=py312h827c3e9_0
  - openssl=3.4.0=h2466b09_0
  - orc=2.0.1=hd8d391b_0
  - packaging=24.1=py312haa95532_0
  - pandas=2.2.2=py312h0158946_0
  - pillow=10.4.0=py312h827c3e9_0
  - pip=24.2=py312haa95532_0
  - plotly=5.24.1=py312hfc267ef_0
  - ply=3.11=py312haa95532_1
  - protobuf=4.25.3=py312h958608f_0
  - psycopg2=2.9.9=py312h2bbff1b_0
  - pyarrow=16.1.0=py312h0158946_0
  - pydeck=0.8.0=py312haa95532_2
  - pygments=2.15.1=py312haa95532_1
  - pyparsing=3.2.0=py312haa95532_0
  - pyqt=5.15.10=py312hd77b12b_0
  - pyqt5-sip=12.13.0=py312h2bbff1b_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py312haa95532_0
  - python=3.12.7=h14ffc60_0
  - python-dateutil=2.9.0post0=py312haa95532_2
  - python-dotenv=0.21.0=py312haa95532_0
  - python-tzdata=2023.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pytz=2024.1=py312haa95532_0
  - pyyaml=6.0.2=py312h827c3e9_0
  - qt-main=5.15.2=h19c9488_10
  - re2=2022.04.01=hd77b12b_0
  - referencing=0.30.2=py312haa95532_0
  - requests=2.32.3=py312haa95532_0
  - rich=13.7.1=py312haa95532_0
  - rpds-py=0.10.6=py312h062c2fa_0
  - scipy=1.14.1=py312h9d85e7c_0
  - setuptools=75.1.0=py312haa95532_0
  - sip=6.7.12=py312hd77b12b_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - smmap=4.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - snappy=1.2.1=hcdb6601_0
  - sqlalchemy=2.0.34=py312h54f65d0_0
  - sqlite=3.45.3=h2bbff1b_0
  - streamlit=1.40.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tbb=2021.8.0=h59b6b97_0
  - tenacity=8.2.3=py312haa95532_0
  - tk=8.6.14=h0416ee5_0
  - toml=0.10.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - toolz=0.12.0=py312haa95532_0
  - tornado=6.4.1=py312h827c3e9_0
  - typing-extensions=4.11.0=py312haa95532_0
  - typing_extensions=4.11.0=py312haa95532_0
  - tzdata=2024b=h04d1e81_0
  - tzlocal=3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - ucrt=10.0.22621.0=h57928b3_1
  - unicodedata2=15.1.0=py312h2bbff1b_0
  - urllib3=2.2.3=py312haa95532_0
  - utf8proc=2.6.1=h2bbff1b_1
  - validators=0.34.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - vc=14.40=h2eaa2aa_1
  - vc14_runtime=14.42.34433=he29a5d6_23
  - vs2015_runtime=14.42.34433=hdffcdeb_23
  - watchdog=4.0.1=py312haa95532_0
  - wheel=0.44.0=py312haa95532_0
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0=py312haa95532_0
  - xz=5.4.6=h8cc25b3_1
  - yaml=0.2.5=he774522_0
  - zipp=3.21.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=h8cc25b3_1
  - zstd=1.5.6=h8880b57_0
  - pip:
      - alembic==1.13.3
      - mako==1.3.6
prefix: C:\Users\7046442\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\app

when I'm tryinf to build the image, I got this error :
> [app 4/4] RUN conda env create --file environment.yml:
1.106 Channels:
1.106  - conda-forge
1.106  - defaults
1.106 Platform: linux-64
1.106 Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
15.69 Solving environment: ...working... failed
50.50
50.50 PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
50.50
50.50   - zstd==1.5.6=h8880b57_0
50.50   - zlib==1.2.13=h8cc25b3_1
50.50   - yaml==0.2.5=he774522_0
50.50   - xz==5.4.6=h8cc25b3_1
50.50   - win_inet_pton==1.1.0=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - wheel==0.44.0=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - watchdog==4.0.1=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - vs2015_runtime==14.42.34433=hdffcdeb_23
50.50   - vc14_runtime==14.42.34433=he29a5d6_23
50.50   - vc==14.40=h2eaa2aa_1
50.50   - utf8proc==2.6.1=h2bbff1b_1
50.50   - urllib3==2.2.3=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - unicodedata2==15.1.0=py312h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - ucrt==10.0.22621.0=h57928b3_1
50.50   - typing_extensions==4.11.0=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - typing-extensions==4.11.0=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - tornado==6.4.1=py312h827c3e9_0
50.50   - toolz==0.12.0=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - tk==8.6.14=h0416ee5_0
50.50   - tenacity==8.2.3=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - tbb==2021.8.0=h59b6b97_0
50.50   - sqlite==3.45.3=h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - sqlalchemy==2.0.34=py312h54f65d0_0
50.50   - snappy==1.2.1=hcdb6601_0
50.50   - sip==6.7.12=py312hd77b12b_0
50.50   - setuptools==75.1.0=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - scipy==1.14.1=py312h9d85e7c_0
50.50   - rpds-py==0.10.6=py312h062c2fa_0
50.50   - rich==13.7.1=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - requests==2.32.3=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - referencing==0.30.2=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - re2==2022.04.01=hd77b12b_0
50.50   - qt-main==5.15.2=h19c9488_10
50.50   - pyyaml==6.0.2=py312h827c3e9_0
50.50   - pytz==2024.1=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - python-dotenv==0.21.0=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - python-dateutil==2.9.0post0=py312haa95532_2
50.50   - python==3.12.7=h14ffc60_0
50.50   - pysocks==1.7.1=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - pyqt5-sip==12.13.0=py312h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - pyqt==5.15.10=py312hd77b12b_0
50.50   - pyparsing==3.2.0=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - pygments==2.15.1=py312haa95532_1
50.50   - pydeck==0.8.0=py312haa95532_2
50.50   - pyarrow==16.1.0=py312h0158946_0
50.50   - psycopg2==2.9.9=py312h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - protobuf==4.25.3=py312h958608f_0
50.50   - ply==3.11=py312haa95532_1
50.50   - plotly==5.24.1=py312hfc267ef_0
50.50   - pip==24.2=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - pillow==10.4.0=py312h827c3e9_0
50.50   - pandas==2.2.2=py312h0158946_0
50.50   - packaging==24.1=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - orc==2.0.1=hd8d391b_0
50.50   - openssl==3.4.0=h2466b09_0
50.50   - openpyxl==3.1.5=py312h827c3e9_0
50.50   - openjpeg==2.5.2=hae555c5_0
50.50   - numpy-base==1.26.4=py312h4dde369_0
50.50   - numpy==1.26.4=py312hfd52020_0
50.50   - numexpr==2.8.7=py312h96b7d27_0
50.50   - more-itertools==10.3.0=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - mkl_random==1.2.7=py312h0158946_0
50.50   - mkl_fft==1.3.10=py312h827c3e9_0
50.50   - mkl-service==2.4.0=py312h2bbff1b_1
50.50   - mkl==2023.1.0=h6b88ed4_46358
50.50   - mdurl==0.1.0=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - matplotlib-base==3.9.2=py312he19b0ae_1
50.50   - matplotlib==3.9.2=py312haa95532_1
50.50   - markupsafe==2.1.3=py312h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - markdown-it-py==2.2.0=py312haa95532_1
50.50   - lz4-c==1.9.4=h2bbff1b_1
50.50   - libwebp-base==1.3.2=h3d04722_1
50.50   - libtiff==4.5.1=hd77b12b_0
50.50   - libthrift==0.15.0=h4364b78_2
50.50   - libssh2==1.11.0=h291bd65_0
50.50   - libprotobuf==4.25.3=hf2fb9eb_0
50.50   - libpq==12.17=h906ac69_0
50.50   - libpng==1.6.39=h8cc25b3_0
50.50   - libgrpc==1.62.2=hf25190f_0
50.50   - libffi==3.4.4=hd77b12b_1
50.50   - libevent==2.1.12=h56d1f94_1
50.50   - libdeflate==1.17=h2bbff1b_1
50.50   - libcurl==8.9.1=h0416ee5_0
50.50   - libclang13==14.0.6=default_h8e68704_1
50.50   - libclang==14.0.6=default_hb5a9fac_1
50.50   - libbrotlienc==1.0.9=h2bbff1b_8
50.50   - libbrotlidec==1.0.9=h2bbff1b_8
50.50   - libbrotlicommon==1.0.9=h2bbff1b_8
50.50   - libboost==1.82.0=h3399ecb_2
50.50   - libabseil==20240116.2=cxx17_h5da7b33_0
50.50   - lerc==3.0=hd77b12b_0
50.50   - lcms2==2.12=h83e58a3_0
50.50   - krb5==1.20.1=h5b6d351_0
50.50   - kiwisolver==1.4.4=py312hd77b12b_0
50.50   - jsonschema-specifications==2023.7.1=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - jsonschema==4.23.0=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - jpeg==9e=h827c3e9_3
50.50   - jinja2==3.1.4=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - intel-openmp==2023.1.0=h59b6b97_46320
50.50   - idna==3.7=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - icu==73.1=h6c2663c_0
50.50   - icc_rt==2022.1.0=h6049295_2
50.50   - htbuilder==0.6.2=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - greenlet==3.0.1=py312hd77b12b_0
50.50   - glog==0.5.0=hd77b12b_1
50.50   - gitpython==3.1.43=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - gflags==2.2.2=hd77b12b_1
50.50   - freetype==2.12.1=ha860e81_0
50.50   - fonttools==4.51.0=py312h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - expat==2.6.3=h5da7b33_0
50.50   - et_xmlfile==1.1.0=py312haa95532_1
50.50   - contourpy==1.3.1=py312h214f63a_0
50.50   - colorama==0.4.6=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - click==8.1.7=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - certifi==2024.8.30=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - cachetools==5.3.3=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - ca-certificates==2024.11.26=haa95532_0
50.50   - c-ares==1.19.1=h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - bzip2==1.0.8=h2bbff1b_6
50.50   - brotli-python==1.0.9=py312hd77b12b_8
50.50   - brotli-bin==1.0.9=h2bbff1b_8
50.50   - brotli==1.0.9=h2bbff1b_8
50.50   - bottleneck==1.3.7=py312he558020_0
50.50   - boost-cpp==1.82.0=h59b6b97_2
50.50   - blinker==1.6.2=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - aws-sdk-cpp==1.10.55=hd77b12b_0
50.50   - aws-crt-cpp==0.18.16=hd77b12b_0
50.50   - aws-checksums==0.1.13=h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - aws-c-sdkutils==0.1.6=h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - aws-c-s3==0.1.51=h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - aws-c-mqtt==0.7.13=h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - aws-c-io==0.13.10=h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - aws-c-http==0.6.25=h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - aws-c-event-stream==0.2.15=hd77b12b_0
50.50   - aws-c-compression==0.2.16=h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - aws-c-common==0.8.5=h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - aws-c-cal==0.5.20=h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - aws-c-auth==0.6.19=h2bbff1b_0
50.50   - attrs==24.2.0=py312haa95532_0
50.50   - arrow-cpp==16.1.0=h7cd61ee_0
50.50   - altair==5.0.1=py312haa95532_0
50.50
50.50 Current channels:
50.50
50.50   - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
50.50   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
50.50   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
50.50
50.50 To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
50.50 looking for, navigate to
50.50
50.50     https://anaconda.org
50.50
50.50 and use the search bar at the top of the page.
50.50
50.50
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c conda env create --file environment.yml" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

did I do somethinf wrong ? if you could help please ?
thanks

Package not found can mean a couple of things:

Incorrect package name or version
Packages not present specified channels
Packages not available for the platform you are building on

Your problem is most likely that your environment file is too specific when specifying dependencies:
altair=5.0.1=py312haa95532_0
That haa95532_0 is a build string that specifies things such as architecture, platform, and build. It is specific to your current machine and should not be included in dependencies files such as environment.yml or requirements.txt

thanks for your time, because environment.yml I create it automatically using conda env export > environment.yml, what is the the correct way to generate environment.yml please ?

conda env export > environment.yml is good for replicating your exact environment but bad for portability as it captures extra information such as build strings. It will also capture all dependencies in your environment including those not relevant to your project.
Rather than manually creating a new environment file, you can edit the output of this command to remove extra information such as build strings and unneeded dependencies.

I used this one conda env export --no-builds | findstr -v "prefix" > environment.yml, and it worked as expected..I have only one issue now is : 56.42 Could not solve for environment specs
56.42 The following packages are incompatible
56.42 ├─ ucrt 10.0.22621.0**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
56.42 ├─ vc 14.40**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
56.42 ├─ vc14_runtime 14.42.34433**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing

Should I delete these dependacies from environment.yml ?

From a quick search, those appear to be visual C++ libraries that are windows specific. You can try removing them but you'll need to verify your application works fine without them. I'd try to exclude them locally first.

@innov-aphp conda export --from-history is a much better approach for exporting your env
